# Can a positive definite kernel expanded as the product form with an arbitrary orthonormal system?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, compact-operators

Notations mostly follow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem.

Mercer's theorem uses the eigenfunctions $\{e_j\}$ of the integral operator as the expansion function. I wonder if we could do the same with an orthonormal system $\{g_j\}$ at hand, that we do not necessarily know if they are eigenfunctions of an integral operator $K$ associated to a given $\kappa$.

We have $\kappa: [a,b] \times [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, a symmetric and continuous kernel. Further, we assume that $\kappa$ is a positive definite kernel on $[a,b]$, that is, $ \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \kappa(x_i, x_j) c_i c_j \geq 0$ holds for for all finite point set $\{x_1, ..., x_n\}\subset[a, b]$ and all choices of $\{c_1,\dotsc,c_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the integral operator on $(L^2(a,b),\mu)$ associated with $\kappa$, that is,
$$ [K \varphi](x) =\int_a^b  \kappa(x,s) f(s)\, d\mu(s),\qquad f\in L^2_\mu(a,b),$$
where $L^2_\mu(a,b)$ is the $L^2$ space with respect to a finite measure $\mu$.

Now, we have $L^2_\mu(a,b)$-orthonormal system $\{g_j\}$ at hand.

**Question**: Does the following hold?
$$
\kappa(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \gamma_j g_j(x)g_j(y),
$$
where $\gamma_j$'s are some constant.

My guess and hope is that it holds with
$$
\gamma_j=\int_{[a,b]\times[a,b]}
 \kappa(y,x) g_j(y) g_j(x) \,d[\mu \otimes \mu](y,x),
$$
as it is the case when $\{g_j\}$'s are the eigenfunctions, i.e., $g_j=e_j$.

The thing I cannot be sure is that the expansion is the product form, by which I mean the sum is of the form $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \gamma_j g_j(x)g_j(y)$, as opposed to $\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty \gamma_{jk} g_j(x)g_k(y)$, which is what we get if we expand $k(x,y)$ in each term naively. Surely the former expansion gives an positive definite ($K$ is a positive operator and thus $\gamma_i=\langle Kg_j,g_j\rangle\ge0$) kernel $\kappa^g$ but not sure if $\kappa=\kappa^g$.

I tried to use the positive definiteness, or the uniqueness of the reproducing kernel but could not argue properly. If this is a well known result I would like a reference.

Comment: the eigenvectors $e_i$ have representations in the $g_k$ basis : $e_i(x) = \sum_k c_{k,i} g_k(x)$ for all $x$ and thus...

Comment: @reuns I thought about it, but could not really conclude anything. E.g., assuming $\sum_j\gamma_jg_j(x)g_j(y)=\sum_j\lambda_je_j(x)e_j(y)$, we must have $\gamma_m=\sum_i\lambda_i c_{m,i}c_{m,i}$ but could not say conversely, etc....

Comment: no, you get $\sum_j \lambda_j e_j(x) e_j(y) =  \sum_j \lambda_j \sum_k \sum_m c_{k,j} c_{m,j} g_k(x) g_m(y)$ so that $c_{k,j} \sum_j \lambda_j \sum_m  c_{m,j}  g_m(y) = \delta_{k,m} \gamma_k$ which implies ...

Comment: @reuns Sorry I am perplexed. Could I ask how did you get the last equation? Why is the left hand side a function of $y$ and right hand side constant? If you meant $\delta_{k,m}\gamma_kg_k(y)$, don't you still get $\gamma_k=\sum_{i}\lambda_ic_{k,i}c_{k,i}$?

Comment: the term is $0$ when $k \ne m$ ... anyway, you should know from finite matrix theory that if a matrix is diagonalizable in a certain basis, then it is not diogonalizable in another (the only case where it is is when the second basis is the same as the first, but where the eigenvalues of mulitplicity $ \ge  2$ have there corresponding subspace basis rotated but still in the same subspace). the theorem extends naturally for linear operators of hilbert spaces.

Comment: @reuns Thank you for the second point. Now it seems really not true that the above hold but I would love a direct or more detailed reasoning.

Comment: @renus Is the first point a "reply to 'how to get the last equality'" or "given the last equality, how to get a contradiction"? I had an impression that you tried to led me to a contradiction, but I still do not how to get the last equality in the third comment or how to derive a contradition. Were you saying 1. the last equality must hold. 2. But $k=m$ we have $c_{m,j}\sum_j\lambda_j\sum_mc_{m,j}g_m(y)=\gamma_m$, which cannot happen, since RHS is a constant contradiction. ?